# invalid syntax for raising an exception inside a class method

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying to `raise` an `AttributeError` inside a class-method, the idea of this method is that if `apply_button` is `None` then apply the exception, else click on the button.

However when I do the following code:

```
import pyautogui
import os

def apply_button_detector(self):
        
    apply_button=pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, r'apply_button.png'), region=(1, 300, 500, 700))
           
    if apply_button is None:
        try:
           print('no apply button')
           raise AttributeError()
                            
    else:
          # click on Apply button
           apply_button_location=pyautogui.center(apply_button)
           pyautogui.click(apply_button_location)
```

It marks me an error at `raise AttributeError()`:

> invalid syntax ()

How could I adjust the function in order to return an AttributeError?

Comment: Why do you have a `try` with no `except` or `finally`? What were you trying to do there?

Comment: Please post the full traceback. The problem is that you have a `try` block without an `except` exception handler. You don't need `try` to raise something. Just take that line out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the `raise` inside a `try` block, but tries need exception handlers. That's what `try` is for - to demark the code that will be handled by one or more `except` or `finally` handlers. Just remove the `try`. Also, since the `raise` interrupts current execution, there is no reason to have an `else` for the remaining code. Its more readable to just leave that part out. Finally, the print seems a bit odd because the `raise` has the information you need. I moved the informational message there.

```
import pyautogui
import os

def apply_button_detector(self):
        
    apply_button=pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, r'apply_button.png'), region=(1, 300, 500, 700))
           
    if apply_button is None:
         raise AttributeError('no apply button')
    # click on Apply button
    apply_button_location=pyautogui.center(apply_button)
    pyautogui.click(apply_button_location)
```